# PopOver frame issue in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller

I display a popover in map view as follows:

[image]

But when i rotate the device, It shows Like:

[image]

**as you see it covers the annotation instead of showing just beside the annotation.**

**My code is as as shown below:**

```
CGPoint annotationPoint = [mapView convertCoordinate:aView.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:mapView];
        float boxDY=annotationPoint.y;
        float boxDX=annotationPoint.x;
        CGRect box = CGRectMake(boxDX,boxDY,5,5);


        UILabel *displayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:box];


         [popView presentPopoverFromRect:displayLabel.frame inView:mapView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


        [displayLabel release];
```

**Help me to solve this problem.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the following method (declared in **UIViewcontroller.h**) :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

You'll probably need to save the state of your viewController (like isPopoverPresented, which annotation etc.) and update the popover's rect accordingly.