# Rotation issue using UIActivityViewController in a MapView

Tags: mkmapview, uipopovercontroller, mkannotation, mkannotationview, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my iOS app I have a Map View that I called `mappa`. 
I just add a UIActivityViewController that appears when a callout is pressed from an annotation View. 
I use this code to display it:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
 calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    [mappa deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0) {

        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self, [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.AppStore.com/iToretto"]]
                                                                                             applicationActivities:nil];

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard ];

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

            UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
            self.annotationPopoverController = pop;

            //show the popover next to the annotation view (pin)
            [pop presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds
                                 inView:view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                               animated:YES];
            self.annotationPopoverController.delegate = self; 
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I rotate this popover, I have a frame Issue ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659786/popover-frame-issue-in-iphone-sdk)). I understand that the solution is to override :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

But when I try to display popover in landscape mode in this way I have multiple errors:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && [self.annotationPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.annotationPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds
                                                      inView:view
                                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                                    animated:YES];
}
```

Because "view.bounds" and "view" is a local declaration of `MKAnnotation`

So, How can I fix it?! Does anyone have a solution?! Thanks in advance.